# A person who can read lines of "hand"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions, word-usage

A person who can read lines of "hand" ?
Is there a word of such a person. As far as I am concerned there is that I am missing?

Comment: Chiromancy: Divination performed by examining the lines in the palms. -Wikipedia.  Palm readers is a 'chiromancer'

Comment: I ♥ χ ! ;^) ...

Answer (score 3):

Such a person is known as a Palmist and the art of reading hand lines is known as Palmistry.